# Partially render a screen in Ember.js when some data doesn't load

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have an Ember route with a model that loads data from a few different places, using `Ember.RSVP.hash`. Each of these results in a call to a different API route in the backend:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            profile: this.store.queryRecord('profile', {}),
            subscriptions: this.store.findAll('subscription'),
            packages: this.store.findAll('package'),
        });
    },
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when *any* of the data calls throws an error, the entire template fails to load. What I would like to do instead is display as much data as is available even in case of an error, with the portions that couldn't be loaded displayed as an empty model of the appropriate type (with some additional error information). However, I don't seem to be able to do this. I tried adding an error handler to the route, but from the error handler there doesn't seem to be any way to continue the transition despite the error.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use service for obtaining such information. Model will be completely loaded but data from service will show after they will be loaded.

Take a look at http://emberigniter.com/render-promise-before-it-resolves/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest passing data down from the route, whether it uses one or more other services to retrieve the data (also from the same author http://emberigniter.com/should-components-load-data/ ). The template can be rendered partially by populating the model provided to the components with separate requests. A good place for this kind of code is in `setupController`. Usually I only add a call to a service from a component if there is a logical coupling between the two eg a component showing a specific ad.

rough example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/netesehasi/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
...
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    return {dataForA:null,dataForB:null,dataForC:null};
  },
  setupController:function(controller,model) {
    this._super.apply(arguments);

    // simulate fetching data
      setTimeout(function(){
        Ember.set(model,'dataForA', 'this is data for component a');
        controller.set('model', model);
      },2000);

      setTimeout(function(){
        Ember.set(model,'dataForB', 'this is data for component b');
        controller.set('model', model);
      },1000);

      setTimeout(function(){
        Ember.set(model,'dataForC', {error:'error for component c'});
        controller.set('model', model);
      },3000);



  }
});
...
```

**hbs**

```
...
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/comp-a">
{{#if data}}
  {{data}}
  {{else}}
  loading...
  {{/if}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/comp-b">
  {{#if data}}
  {{data}}
  {{else}}
  loading...
  {{/if}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/comp-c">
  {{#if data}}
    {{#if data.error}}
      {{data.error}}
    {{else}}
      {{data}}
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
  loading...
  {{/if}}
  </script>
...
```

Comment: Any explanation when downvoting, would be greatly appreciated. I'd really like to exchange ideas, thanks!